# Не могу понять разницу между property, магическими методами и дескрипторами данных

Tags: python, ооп

Понятно, что дескриптор более удобен для создания похожих обьектов - переменных, но чем отличается присвоение не совсем понятно. С property и магическими методами setattr, getattr, delattr  - полная путаница. Если кто-то может пояснить, буду благодарен

Comment: property реализуется с помощью дескриптора, дескриптор реализуется через кучку магических методов